# How to complete an Observable of Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

hi Have an (NgRx) Action that tirgger a function (that should return an observable) that has a loop, for each round of the loop I need to emit (next) a value, the function in the loop that fetch the data return an Observable, I want to complete the observable that has the loop when all the observable complete:

here is the code:

```
      public outerFunction(
        collections: someObject
      ): Observable<someOtherObject> {

        const outerObservable$ = new Observable<Observable<someOtherObject>>(
          (observer) => {

            const collKeys = Object.keys(collections);
            for (const id of collKeys) {
              if (collections[id]) {
                const innerObs$ = this.functionThatReturnsObs(
                  collections[id]
                )
                observer.next(innerObs$);
              }
              // observer.complete(); <-- If I complete here the stream is interrupted
            }
          }
        );
return outerObservable$.pipe(mergeAll());
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I found the answer from the [RxJs Docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatAll)

the code was totally fine without the complete since at the end I called `mergeAll()`

> mergeAll subscribes to an Observable that emits Observables, also
>   known as a higher-order Observable. Each time it observes one of these
>   emitted inner Observables, it subscribes to that and delivers all the
>   values from the inner Observable on the output Observable. **The output
>   Observable only completes once all inner Observables have completed.**

at the end mergeAll() will complete my observable

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this

```
return outerObservable$.pipe(mergeMap(res=>merge(res)))
```

if that doesn't work you can process it like a ordinary array

```
   public outerFunction(
        collections: someObject
      ): Observable<someOtherObject> {
            const innerObs$=[]
            const collKeys = Object.keys(collections);
            for (const id of collKeys) 
              if (collections[id]) 
                innerObs$.push(this.functionThatReturnsObs(
                  collections[id]
                ))

             return merge(innerObs$);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, ok but then, where I should to complete?

Comment: after for .. loop